# Using exec 1>&2 in a POSIX shell script function. Will it interfere with other io-redirects?

Tags: scripting, io-redirection, posix

I am in process of writing a POSIX shell script.

I have one function, which redirects (almost) all output to standard error stream like that:

```sh
# print something to stderr
printf "..." $var 1>&2
```

It has been pointed out to me that there is a way to redirect all of the function's output with:

```sh
# redirect all output to standard error stream
exec 1>&2
```

keeping this line in the beginning of the function.

If there were no other redirects, I would simply agree probably, but I have there a test for color support:

```sh
# check if we have color support
if command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Basically, I don't know how the `exec` works, and I don't need to know much in detail now, I just need to know if that `exec` line will interfere with the above color support test anyhow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec <redirection>` will redirect the current shell's (or subshell's) I/O streams. And since commands started by the shell inherit the shell's I/O streams, those redirections will affect them, with command-specific redirections applied on top.

So, with something like:

```sh
exec >/some/file 2>&1
foo >/another/file
```

- After the `exec`, the shell's stdout goes `/some/file`, and stderr also goes to `/some/file`.
- When starting foo, the shell redirects foo's stdout to `/another/file`, but stderr is inherited unchanged and will go to `/some/file`.

In these commands:

```sh
command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You're not using the inherited stdout/stderr streams at all. First, stdout is redirected to `/dev/null`, then stderr as well. So *that* particular `exec` line won't affect these commands.